# CHwndRenderTarget is wrong size

Tags: mfc, window, rendering, rendertarget

This bug is driving me nuts.
I have an MFC application with a window in which I can draw and interact. The problem is that the size of the `CHwndRenderTarget` does not match the actual size of the window (I compare this using the `CRect` gotten from `GetClientRect()`).
This results in all interaction being offset from where my mouse pointer actually is (not ideal).
I have tried to `ReSize()` the `CHwndRenderTarget` with the correct values but it always returns false.
Why would the `CHwndRenderTarget` be the wrong size?

Here's the code that I'm using to check sizes:

```
CRect clientRect;
GetClientRect(&clientRect);
//clientRect size is 1411 x 817

CD2DSizeF size = pRenderTarget->GetSize();
//RenderTarget size is 1128 x 653


//When I try to resize the RenderTarget, it always returns false
CD2DSizeU newSize( ( clientRect.right - clientRect.left ), ( clientRect.top - clientRect.bottom ) );
bool success = pRenderTarget->Resize(newSize); //returns false
```

Comment: It is off by how many pixels?

Comment: Please show more code.